# How to make two classes reference the same object and its methods

Tags: java, class, object, methods, reference

So i'm trying to make an object I've created have the same variables and methods as a corresponding object in a second class without using static methods etc. The best way i can think of doing this is perhaps using a method that goes something like:

```
 public void setObjectReference(Object object){
 object = this.object;
 }
```

My problem with this is that i want to reference a few objects between classes and this approach would mean that i'd have to make a method with a different `this.object;` changing the name of that for each method. This seems to be a fairly inefficient way to go about it and i'm sure there's some better way to make two objects in two classes reference the same instance of said object.

Cheers

Edit:

I am trying to use and object called name, in this object there is a few methods, namely `getName()` `setName()` etc. i want to be able to set a value using `setName()` in my first class and then use that in my second class using `getName()`. I am trying to implement this in a javafx application communicating between controllers

Hope that helps somewhat

Comment: .... this makes no sense. 
so, you would assume that if you had a class Boy and a class Girl, just because they provide the same members, they are interchangeable, and one Object can be both a Girl and a Boy?

Comment: `object = this.object` changes nothing, if object is a member of you class.

Comment: @NaN it re-references the local object variable, which is indeed a bit a waste of code. I assume he meant this.object = object;

Comment: @Stultuske i am trying to make one object reference another in a second class, so when, for example, i were to use something like a `setValue()` in class #1, then in class#2 the variable that could be returned from a `getValue()` method is equivalent. Or is that approach unnecessary and am i missing something?

Comment: Tell us more about the problem you are trying to solve.  The approach you're talking about is very atypical for an object-oriented paradigm.

Comment: @scottb ok give me a minute and ill add something to the question

Comment: so ... both classes have a variable of the same type? then you can use a setter, sure. but why pass an instance of Object? just pass the correct type.

Comment: @Stultuske i have added some more info to question if that can shed any light on what i'm talking about

Comment: @scottb I dont know if it helps, but i've added some to the question

Comment: You want to use a value returned by setName .... setName is not supposed to return any value. Your edit just made it more confusing.

Comment: @Stultuske Sorry, rephrased that, have a look again

Comment: "i want to be able to set a value using setName() in my first class and then use that in my second class using getName()."  It sounds like you might use the Binding API of JavaFX that let's you bind the values of properties in one object to values of properties in another.  Have a look at the Binding API.

Comment: @scottb Will do, i've looked at the binding API previously, but not in any real depth

Comment: The method you propose using is a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

You are on right way but you mixing objects and names. You don't need the same name to access the same value - you need the same object. One of approaches to co communicate between 2 classes is to have common object and use it in both classes. Something like this

```
class Context{
  String Name;
  public void setName(String name){
    this.Name=name;
  }
  public String getName(){
    return Name;
  }
}

class Controller1{
   Context context;
   public Controller1(Context context){
      this.context=context;
   }
   public void someMethod(){
      context.setName("Alex");
   }
}
class Controller2{
   Context context;
   public Controller2(Context context){
      this.context=context;
   }
   public void anotherMethod(){
      String nameFromFirtsController=context.getName();
   }
}
```

Of course a lot is missing including synchronization and there are more efficient approaches like Observer/Observable or messaging but we are talking your approach and I want to show the basic idea.

P.S. You definitely mean

```
this.object = object;
```

to save value within your class instance.

Comment: i've just tried using this but i get a few errors, `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` , `java.lang.InstantiationException`. As you can probably tell i'm not the most experienced with java, but it seems to be the constructors of the controllers that are causing the errors, i'm not sure if you can or can't use constuctors in a javafx controller, i would have assumed you could but perhaps not

Comment: That was basic explanation with basic example. Instead of controller constructor you can use setContext(Context context) method.